# PhpMyAdmin messed up my routing. How do I fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, routes, server, phpmyadmin

So, I wanted to have a one page application with a router. Meaning that I would get the request uri and use it as my routing parameter.
I currently use a VPS running Ubuntu 22.04, and after installing phpMyAdmin (which by default uses the uri /phpmyadmin for its entry page), my router is basically useless. Now, instead of having the request uri being a parameter, it behaves as it does by default.
This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried looking through some config files, but I can't seem to find what exactly I can modify.